# Blank and squared frame on every page [ GOOGLE CHROME CANARY ]

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, google-chrome-canary

I have no idea on how it came to this point. On every page I browse, as I scroll it down, a blank and squared frame appears over the content.

Examples:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed or malware? Try resetting Chrome. Menu -> Settings -> Show more settings at bottom -> Reset

Comment: I have Disconnect and MangaViewer installed only, none of which are malware